# Use live video as a screensaver

Tags: windows-10, screensaver

I have a link to a website with a live video feed. I'd like that live video to be my screensaver when I walk away from my computer.

I've googled "using video for screensaver" but they all seem to involve downloading a video file and putting into a loop. I want to display what's currently happening.

Comment: Try asking Google about “url as screensaver.” This should get you enough information so that you can use any web page as your screensaver, and, by extension any video (as long as the video has its own URL).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the closes thing you can get

https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/18167/set-a-video-as-your-desktop-wallpaper-with-vlc/

simply open the website in VLC as a media file and it "should" work. I can not find any documentation that it will or will not work with a live video feed on a website.